# How to use nextElementSibling in Lightning Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to use the nextElementSibling in liightning controller but its showing error, what is the alternative of nextElementSibling to use, below is the sample code.

```
<div class="panel">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>

        <button class="btm" aura:id="btId" onclick="{!c.open}">Section 3</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Lorem ipsum ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
```

Here is the controller code

```
open : function(component, event, helper) {
    var acc =  component.find("btm");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        $A.util.toggleClass(acc, "active");

        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do - your code is not really helping that much

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with `nextElementSibling`. I believe, after Summer'16 dynamically changing style.display in Lightning Component may not work properly. You can follow the Lightning Components Developer Guide to [Dynamically Showing or Hiding Markup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_show_hide_markup.htm).

You have to modify the code as below.

Component:

```
<aura:component >
    <div class="panel">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button class="btm" aura:id="btId" onclick="{!c.open}">Section 3</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>Lorem ipsum ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    open : function(component, event, helper) {
        var target = event.currentTarget;
        var panel = target.nextElementSibling;
        $A.util.toggleClass(panel, "toggle");
    }
})
```

CSS

```
/*toggleCss.css*/
.THIS.toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

> Update

If you are using `force:slds` in you Lightning application then you can simply use `$A.util.toggleClass(panel, "slds-hide");` without implementing any CSS.

Comment: Or you can simply do $A.util.toggleClass(panel, "slds-hide"); and avoid using CSS :)

Comment: @Rao Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are trying to do, but hopefully this will put you on the right path:

Controller:

```
open: function(component, event, helper) {
  var acc = component.find("btId");
  //check for array as it seems you are finding either and array or a single component
  if (Array.isArray(acc)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      helper.toggleVisibility(component,acc[i]);
    }
  } else {
    helper.toggleVisibility(component,acc);
  }
},
```

Helper:

```
toggleVisibility: function(component, subcmp) {
  $A.util.toggleClass(subcmp, "active");
  var panel = subcmp.getElement().nextElementSibling;
  $A.util.toggleClass(panel, "slds-hide");
}
```